# How to Navigate to another page when click on layout in app.xaml.cs page?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How to Navigate to another page when click on arrow in the pushpin layout?

App.xaml page code:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuItemsStyle" TargetType="sltkit:MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="sltkit:MenuItem">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                       Margin="24,0" 
                                       FontSize="26"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                                       Margin="24,0" 
                                       FontSize="22"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DatetimeAdded}" 
                                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                                       Margin="24,0" 
                                       FontSize="22"/>
                            <Image  Source="/MyBuddies;component/Images/decline.png" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="200,0" Stretch="Fill" Name="imgDecline"  >
                            </Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="MenuStyle" TargetType="sltkit:ContextMenu">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border CornerRadius="8" Margin="24" 
                               BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush 
                                   StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" 
                                                 Offset="0.0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" 
                                                 Offset="0.5"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>

in mainpage.xaml 

<my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                         <my:Pushpin
                          Background="Blue"
                           Location="{Binding Location}" Tap="Pushpin_Tap">
                                <sltkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <sltkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False">
                                        <sltkit:MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemsStyle}"/>
                                    </sltkit:ContextMenu>
                                </sltkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            </my:Pushpin>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </my:MapItemsControl>
```

tap on pushpin displaying description .Need to place one arrow in that layout  when click on that pass some values to another page.how to acheive this?please tell me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good practice to write some UI code in App.xaml. App.xaml and App.xaml.cs are intended for handling the app lifetime events like Launching, Closing, Activated and Deactivated events and for sharing some global data.

If you still want to use, then in the code behind you can use the following code to Navigate to another page from App.xaml

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/AnotherPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```